Filter in MongoDB doesn't work as I expect
I have this collection
 public class Notification
 {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Recipients")]
    public List<RecipientsDocument> Recipients { get; set; }
    
    [BsonElement("Read")]
    public bool Read { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class RecipientsDocument
{
    [BsonElement("Typer")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("CodeId")]
    public Guid? CodeId { get; set; }
}

And this filter class
public class NotificationQueryFilter
{
    public string? CodeFilter { get; set; }
    public TypeRecipientsEnum Type { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> CodeIds { get; set; }
}

In RecipientsDocument class this property is new -> public Guid? CodeId { get; set; }
and this is is the new property on which I have to make the new filter
In this method I search for documents based on filters
public async Task<List<Notification>> GetByCode(string code, int PageNumber, int PageSize,   List<Guid> codeIds = null)
{
    var filter = BuildFilter(new NotificationQueryFilter()
    {
        CodeFilter = code,
        Type = TypeRecipientsEnum.Chief,
        CodeIds = codeIds?.ToList()
    });

    int skip = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;
    var sortBuilder = Builders<Notification>.Sort;
    var sort = sortBuilder.Descending(nameof(Notification.DataInserimento));

    var docs = await GetCollection().Find(filter).Sort(sort).Skip(skip).Limit(PageSize).ToListAsync();
    return docs;
}

private static FilterDefinition<Notification> BuildFilter(NotificheQueryFilter item)
{
    var filterDefinition = Builders<Notification>.Filter;
    FilterDefinition<Notification> filter = FilterDefinition<Notification>.Empty;

    // Code filter
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.CodeFilter))
    {
        filter &= filterDefinition.ElemMatch(x => x.Recipients, dest => dest.Code == item.CodeFilter);
    }

    // CodeIds Filter
    if(item.CodeIds != null && item.CodeIds.Any())
    {
        filter &= filterDefinition.Where(x => x.Recipients.Any(d => item.CodeIds.Any(z=> z == d.CodeId))); ***<- Doesn't works***
    }

    return filter;
}

This is an example of documents present in the collection
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65c1e164d57e35d0dcbc10ab"
  },
  "Text": "For me is Ok!!!",
  "Recipients": [
    {
      "Type": "Chief",
      "Code": "AB_98",
      "CodeId": "a305f36f-7ff0-4fe2-8aa9-7029242f2dbb"
    }
  ],
  "Read": true
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65c1e22bd57e35d0dcbc10ac"
  },
  "Text": "For me is Ok!!! 2",
  "Recipients": [
    {
      "Type": "Chief",
      "Code": "AB_98"
    }
  ],
  "Read": true
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65c1e230d57e35d0dcbc10ad"
  },
  "Text": "For me is Ok!!! 3",
  "Recipients": [
    {
      "Type": "Chief",
      "Code": "AB_98"
    }
  ],
  "Read": true
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65c1f5c9d57e35d0dcbc10ae"
  },
  "Text": "",
  "Recipients": [
    {
      "Type": "Chief",
      "Code": "AB_98",
      "CodeId": "c8244221-2752-4b06-9d5a-a2bb6f14ef54"
    }
  ],
  "Read": true
}]

When I call
var list = GetByCode("AB_98",1,10,new List<Guid>(){"a305f36f-7ff0-4fe2-8aa9-7029242f2dbb","c8244221-2752-4b06-9d5a-a2bb6f14ef54"});

I expect records 1 and 4 to be retrieved but the list is always empty

try use ElemMatch like filterDefinition.ElemMatch(x => x.Recipients, dest => dest.CodeIds.Any(d => item.CodeIds.Any(z=> z == d)));

Recipients doesn't have a property called CodeIds but CodeId(single not list)

sorry about that. fix filterDefinition.ElemMatch(x => x.Recipients, dest => item.CodeIds.Any(z=> z == dest.CodeId));

I have tried your code out and I am getting 2 items that are containing codes from the filter. What was your expectation? You wanted to get items without any code too ?

I am getting empty result, I actually expect to have two records

Perhaps you have Problems somewhere else. For example the call of the method you have pasted could not work. I am calling it this way, with parsing of guids:         var list = await GetByCode("AB_98",1,10, [             Guid.Parse("a305f36f-7ff0-4fe2-8aa9-7029242f2dbb"),             Guid.Parse("c8244221-2752-4b06-9d5a-a2bb6f14ef54")         ]); 

This is correct....I try(filterDefinition.ElemMatch(x => x.Recipients, dest => item.CodeIds.Any(z=> z == dest.CodeId));) but I received this error Command find failed: $expr can only be applied to the top-level document

Believe that you are storing the GUID as a string in your document.
While MongoDB translates the query from Fluent, it translates the GUID value as:
CSUUID("<Guid>")

This could result in unexpected behavior in the query by comparing the value in the document field which is a string value.
Make sure you register the serializer (GUID as string) before the query:
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));

public async Task<List<Notification>> GetByCode(string code, int PageNumber, int PageSize, List<Guid> codeIds = null)
{
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));

    // Following existing implementation 
    ...
}

Reference: Storing GUIDs as strings in MongoDB with C#
